# async await with timer.Tick

Tags: c#, events, timer, async-await

i am currently extending a WinForms Application with async await.

The MainForm is waiting for some Barcode Scan Input and reacting on the MainForm_KeyDown Event.

To avoid that a user can type some nonsense on the keyboard and making the real scan fail, i implemented a Timer which clears the ScanInput string all 300ms.

I'd like to show some snippet of the implementation:

```
    public SomeCtor()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(){ Interval = 300 };

        _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScanInput = String.Empty;
    }

    private async void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                await OnScanBarcodeAsync(ScanInput);
                break;
        }

        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

Now my question is:
Is it possible that i'll get async await problems with this kind of implementation caused by the Timer? The application testibility is pretty bad btw.

Comment: I think you may have a problem with this. Most likely, barcode scanner spits out one character at a time, so there's a chance the timer ticks will clear the legitimate input in the middle of the run of numbers.

Comment: yes you are right. the scanner is typing like a human but as fast as it would be in a copy&paste process. but this would be a basic coding problem not an async await problem. (if that case turns up i could increase the timer).

Comment: I think your best bet is to not mess with the user input at all; all barcode scanners act like "keyboards", so anyone using a barcode would already know not to mash the keyboard at the same time they're scanning. That would also allow the user to type the code manually in case it can't be read.

Comment: in a brave world you might be right. but excluding user failures should be better! there is no option to type in the barcode manually.